# how can i get the right change for $2.30 in change calculator program?

Tags: c++

I wrote this change calculator, and everything works fine except the case when I input $2.30 as value for `changeAmount`. How can I fix it?
This the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double changeAmount;
int fives;
int ones;
int quarters;
int dimes;
int nickels;
int pennies;
cout <<"*** A Very Simple Change Machine ***" <<endl;
cout <<endl;
cout <<"Enter change amount --> ";
cin >>changeAmount;
cout <<"The change amount is $" <<changeAmount <<" ." <<endl;
cout <<endl;

if (changeAmount < 0)
{
    cout << "Invalid amount." <<endl;
}
else
{

    changeAmount = changeAmount * 100;
    changeAmount = int(changeAmount);

    fives = changeAmount / 500 ;
    changeAmount -= fives * 500;

    ones = changeAmount / 100 ;
    changeAmount -= ones * 100;

    quarters = changeAmount / 25;
    changeAmount -= quarters * 25;

    dimes = changeAmount / 10;
    changeAmount -= dimes * 10;

    nickels = changeAmount / 5;
    changeAmount -= nickels * 5;

    pennies = changeAmount / 1 ;
    changeAmount -= pennies * 1;

    cout <<"Your change is given as :" <<endl;
    cout <<"    $5 bill (s)   : " <<fives <<endl;
    cout <<"    $1 bill (s)   : " <<ones <<endl;
    cout <<"    quarter (s)   : " <<quarters <<endl;
    cout <<"    dime (s)      : " <<dimes <<endl;
    cout <<"    nickel (s)    : " <<nickels <<endl;
    cout <<"    penny (ies)   : " <<pennies <<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, you should step through your code with a debugger to find out where the problem is.

Comment: Start by using the debugger. As a note, your `pennies = changeAmount / 1;` is the same as `pennies = changeAmount;`, and you can remove the `changeAmount -= pennies * 1;` entirely because it's meaningless. (You don't refer to `changeAmount` any further after that at all, so there's no need to update the value, and if you needed to you could use `changeAmount = 0;` to avoid the unnecessary multiplication and subtraction.)

Comment: floating-point for financial calculations. Ouch, that hurts!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is with how decimals are stored in the system. 2.30 is stored as 2.29.... and when you multiply by 100 and take the integer portion you get 229. When multiplying by 100 make sure to round up using the round function. Make sure to include Math library.

```
else
{

    changeAmount = round(changeAmount * 100);
    changeAmount = int(changeAmount);

}
```

Comment: actually I just noticed that when I start debugging. I don't know how to use a round function but I thought about adding 0.0000000001 to `changeAmount` after multiplying by 100.

Comment: Just #include<Math> in the header, and then use the code I posted above.

Comment: I had to use `ceil` function because round didnt work. but it worked. thanks :)

Comment: The ciel function always rounds up, thus will cause problems when the system stores a decimal slightly larger than what you want. For example 1.1 is stored as 1.1000000000000001 if you use ciel(100 * 1.1) you will get 111 instead of 110 thus you want to round to the nearest integer using  changeAmount = round(changeAmount * 100);

Comment: its telling me the function `round` is undefined.

Comment: are you using a double or a float for change amount now? If you use a double round(changeamount*100); will work, if you use a float use roundf(changeamount*100); I changed 2 lines of your code as you posted and it worked. #include<math.h> at the top and the line changeamounbt = round(changeamount*100);  and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing modulo `arithmetics` using a double. This does not work reliably. You can change the type of `changeAmount` to `int` to make the example work. (You might want to introduce an second varialbe that stores the double read from the input.)

Comment: actually I changed the type from double to float and it worked .

Comment: @AdamRich: That's just a work-around.

Comment: but you are just being lucky because of the internal representation.

Comment: @AdamRich So, it works for 2.30? How many other input have you checked? Some other inputs will probably still be wrong. So, using float does not solve your problem.

Comment: @Caramiriel Ah, workaround - that's enough if your requirements fix the input to be 2.3 and the hardware and compiler to remain as is :)

Comment: I just want to get around it. Its a project. Lol

Answer (score 0):

compile this and see what happens:

```
changeAmount = changeAmount * 100;
cout <<"The change amount is $" <<changeAmount <<" ." <<endl; //230
changeAmount = int(changeAmount);
cout <<"The change amount is $" <<changeAmount <<" ." <<endl; //229
```